# Finding Max and Return column name in ms excel

Tags: excel, max

I am trying to both Find the maximum of a column and return the the sub heading the max would fall under eg:

```
   A     B
Damian  100
        200
        300
        400

Damian1 100
        200
        300
        900
```

I am tring to return `Damian1 900` I have simply tried the MAX function however it only returns 900, I am asking for assistance please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simply matter to retrieve the maximum value of a column. Once you know that, you can use its position to govern the scope of a last-text-value from column A.

```
=VLOOKUP("zzz", $A$1:INDEX($A:$A, MATCH(MAX($B:$B),$B:$B, 0)), 1)
```

[image: Approximate lookup from MAX]